# Why can't I send emails?

Tags: magento-1.9, email, review

I want to get a notify email after a customer added a review and installed an extension for this, but the email can't be send :(.

The exception log details:

```
exception 'Exception' with message 'This letter cannot be sent.' in /home/magento/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php:375
Stack trace:
#0 /home/magento/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(509): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->send('test@gmx.de', 'tester', Array)
#1 /home/magento/www/app/code/local/Magegiant/Newreviewnotify/Model/Observer.php(71): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->sendTransactional('newreviewnotify...', 'support', 'test@gmx.de', 'tester', Array)
#2 /home/magento/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Magegiant_Newreviewnotify_Model_Observer->reviewReviewSaveAfter(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#3 /home/magento/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Magegiant_Newreviewnotify_Model_Observer), 'reviewReviewSav...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#4 /home/magento/www/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('review_save_aft...', Array)
#5 /home/magento/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(466): Mage::dispatchEvent('review_save_aft...', Array)
#6 /home/magento/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(319): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_afterSave()
#7 /home/magento/www/app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php(189): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#8 /home/magento/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Review_ProductController->postAction()
#9 /home/magento/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('post')
#10 /home/magento/www/app/code/community/Mdl/UnderConstruction/Controller/Router/Standard.php(72): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 /home/magento/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mdl_UnderConstruction_Controller_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /home/magento/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 /home/magento/www/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /home/magento/www/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}
```

After this I have checked the Template.php and logged this:

```
public function isValidForSend()
{


Mage::Log(var_export(!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('system/smtp/disable'),true).';'.var_export($this->getSenderName(),true).';'.var_export($this->getSenderEmail(),true).';'.var_export($this->getTemplateSubject(),true),null,'email.log');

    return !Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('system/smtp/disable')
        && $this->getSenderName()
        && $this->getSenderEmail()
        && $this->getTemplateSubject();
}
```

The result was:

```
2014-12-12T10:12:07+00:00 DEBUG (7): true;'Test Onlineshop';'test_support@gmx.de';'New Review'
```

So I don't know where the problem is, because the variables looks ok. Hope u can help me

UPDATE:

I get no errors anymore, after clearing cache, but I also get no email notification, the same problem exists with the magento contact form :/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a server related item

Comment: Yep, as brent said, there is no way we can debug this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue happened to both the extension and Magento's built-in contact form, it seem like a server related issue more than application related.

Please make sure that the mail services of your server is running properly and if you are using PHP Mail, try to switch to SMTP instead.

You can also consider using a third-party transactional mailing service (which is recommended) like Mandrill to send out emails with SMTP.

**UPDATE (JULY 28, 2016):** Mandrill stopped offering their free service but there are still other providers offering similar service, like SendGrid and Mailgun.

Comment: Jepp the central issue was a server related item, but the extension works only if a store email is entered in the extension settings, same with the contact form settings, but now I am using the same store email everywhere and it works.